# i want removing any asymmetric column value in mysql data base

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
from message m , message_viewer v 
where m.id = v.message_id 
group by m.author_id , v.viewer_id, m._date

id | author_id | viewer_id | read
1  |    103    |    102    | 0
2  |    102    |    103    | 1
3  |    101    |    103    | 0
4  |    103    |    101    | 0
```

i want the result to be

```
id | author_id | viewer_id | read
1  |    103    |    102    | 0
4  |    103    |    101    | 0
```

Comment: You have a `GROUP BY` but no aggregating function, so the row that `GROUP BY` returns for each group will be arbitrary. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to aggregate your results by the unique combination of authors and viewers, here's one option using `least` and `greatest`:

```
select max(m.id) as id,
    least(m.author_id, mv.viewer_id) as author_id,
    greatest(m.author_id, mv.viewer_id) as viewer_id
from message m 
  join message_viewer mv on m.id = mv.message_id
group by least(m.author_id, mv.viewer_id),
    greatest(m.author_id, mv.viewer_id)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65a2ac/2)

This applies the `max` aggregate to return the message id -- without it, you'll just receive an arbitrary result returned.  It also wasn't clear from your question where the `read` column comes from.